# How to have GULP bundel libraries installed by Bower, ASP.Net 5

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core, bower

I have installed both `jQuery` and `jQuery-Validation` in my ASP.Net 5 application using the new Bower system. This has crated a folder called `lib` which contains a folder for both packages. In the folder for the packages there are LOTS of files and subfolders and after some digging around it looks like I only need to use the `.js` files in the `dist` folder.

I am also using `gulp` for bundling and minification but I am not sure how to configure it so it will add the files form the `dist` folders along with my own custom `JavaScript` files.

I am very new to both `Gulp` and `Bower` but so far they look far more cumbersome, annoying, and complex then the old `NuGet` and ASP.Net 2.5 Bundling and Minification way.

My Gulp (generated by VS2015 for me):
    /// 
    "use strict";

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

EDIT:
I just added `jquery.validatie.unobtrusive` and it does not have a `dist` folder just some `json` files and the core `.js` file at the package root so how do I make sure I am grabbing all the right stuff here?

Comment: I'd recommend not using bower. Most bower packages have an NPM equivalent and even for the ones that don't package.json allows you to reference git repositories.

Comment: @MatthewRath I have never heard of NPM, I am using Bower because that is what MS sets you up for and (I can't find it now) I had read they are dropping support for NuGet

Comment: ... If you are using NodeJS to run gulp how can you not know what NPM is?

Comment: @MatthewRath Am I using NodeJS? I don't know I just right click on Gulp -> Task Runner Explorer => Right Click Clean/Min -> Run

Comment: Gulp is a task runner for NodeJS. NodeJS also has it's own baked in dependency manager called [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Comment: @MatthewRath Is NPM supported with VS 2015 and ASP.Net 5? Also what did you mean by "package.json allows you to reference git repositories"? You mean NuGet or Github?

Comment: NPM comes baked into the typical install of NodeJS, if VS is not supporting it... actually i wouldn't be too surprised since microsoft isnt that great -_-

Comment: and i mean any git based repo whether it's on github or bitbucket doesnt matter.

Comment: Also I think you're mistaken about something. NodeJS and NPM are completely separate from VS. VS just provides an interface to these command line based programs. But that shouldn't mean you cant access these things from the command line yourself. You dont need VS to run gulp.

Comment: I'd recommend you go and watch / read some [tutorials on gulp](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLnpHn493BHE2RsdyUNpbiVn-cfuV7Fos). The one i've linked is pretty old and some of the plugins (tasks) might be out of date. But note he's running it with sublime which isnt a fully fledged IDE it's just a text editor (albeit a very fancy one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dist folder is under webroot:

> paths.dist = paths.webroot + "dist/**/*.js";
>   ..
>   gulp.task("min:js", function () {
>      return gulp.src([paths.js, paths.dist, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })

The key is that you set the source folders that gulp pulls files from. Notice that I added my paths.dist to the array? That adds that folder and all js files under it to gulp. If you need another folder, add another property to paths and add it to the array.

Comment: The `dist` folder is in `wwwroot/lb/PackageName/Dist` but now after installing jquery.validate.unobtrusive I find that for that one there is no dist folder, it just sits at the package's root